# PostGIS polygon edge analysis (orientation, edge length)

Tags: python, postgis, polygon, analysis

I am rather new to the world of GIS and especially PostGIS, so please excuse me if the answer seems evident...

I would like to do analysis on a number of buildings. One thing I am interested in is their facade surfaces along with the respective orientation. As illustrated in the picture below, I would like to have the length and (normal) orientation of all edges in a series of polygons. In the example I highlighted only one surface.

[image]

A result table *could* look like this:

```
building_id | edge_id | orientation | edge_length
-------------------------------------------------
      1     |    1    |     315     |    10.0
      1     |    2    |      45     |     7.0
      1     |   ...   |     ...     |     ...
```

However, I am not sure if it is a smart way to store the result for further processing (e.g. calculate distance from edge to next building, etc.). So my question is twofold:

1. Is there an efficient PostGIS function that can analyze a polygon's edges? In case there is no native PostGIS function I would alternatively be interested in an Python-based approach.
2. What would be a smart way to store the result in a PostGIS table, since the polygons may have different numbers of edges?

Comment: First create the segments of the polygon: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595635/how-to-convert-polygon-data-into-line-segments-using-postgis
Then the startpoint and the endpoint coordinates should go to columns like x1,y1 and x2,y2 and than ST_Azimuth(ST_Startpoint(geometries), ST_Endpoint(geometries)). (http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Azimuth.html)

Comment: @TamasKosa: You have the essence of a good answer. Why not expand it into one? Also, for normals, azimuths need +/- pi/2.

Comment: @TamasKosa This is an approach I was also thinking about. Use [ST_ExteriorRing](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ExteriorRing.html) and then get the azimuths as you say.

How would I ideally store the results, since buildings can have different number of edges? In a table like I described above?

I agree with MartinF, this is almost an answer ;)

Comment: Just curious, why do you want normals ... sun exposure?

Comment: The first part of your question has been answered -- you can use ST_Dumppoints and ST_Azimuth. For the second part, as there are no spatial elements to the output, I would think a link to polygonID and edge_id as you have would be find.

Comment: @JohnBarça Thanks! I wonder why no one turns their good hints into a full answer :) Since, I have little experience with SQL, I can't quite figure out how to put things together. Will keep trying.

Comment: @MartinF All sorts of analysis. Exposure, shading, radiation exchange, visualization, etc.

Comment: @n1000. A good question. I have to write something similar for work at some point, to find possible north facing roofs in the ever so sunny UK. I am really busy today, but I'll post an answer later/tomorrow, if no one else does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yesterday I had no time to create it in details... See my solution in 4 steps:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW bd_segment AS
SELECT
      ST_PointN(geom, generate_series(1, ST_NPoints(geom)-1)) AS sp,
      ST_PointN(geom, generate_series(2, ST_NPoints(geom)  )) AS ep
    FROM
       -- extract the individual linestrings
       (SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Boundary(the_geom))).geom
       FROM bd) AS linestrings;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW bd_segment_geom AS
SELECT sp, ep, st_makeline(sp, ep) 
FROM bd_segment;

CREATE OR REPLACE view bd_segment_id AS 
SELECT bd.gid, row_number() 
    OVER (order by bd.gid), degrees(st_azimuth(ff.sp, ff.ep)-1.57079633) AS az_deg,
    ST_LENGTH(ff.st_makeline) , ff.st_makeline FROM bd_segment_geom ff
JOIN bd ON st_touches(ff.st_makeline, bd.the_geom)
GROUP BY bd.gid, ff.sp, ff.ep, ff.st_makeline;

UPDATE bd_segment_id
SET az_deg = az_deg + 360
WHERE az_deg < 0;
```

The last query give you the building ids with a spatial join using st_touches. Hope it helps.
Update - In qgis the solution looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Impressive! I got it to work. Thank you so much! It becomes a little slow with a large number of buildings. The azimuths are not normals right now. Would you also have an idea how to address that? I am not sure how to find the "exterior" side of the polygon.

Comment: add 90 deggrees to the azimuth in radian like this: degrees(st_azimuth(ff.sp, ff.ep)+1.57079633). It will generate sometimes values that bigger than 360. but with an update query you can replace those. If you would like to use as a static view create "CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW" and it won't be slow just at the first time.

Comment: Not quite. Assuming North is 0°, this will give the normal towards the *inside* of the polygon / building (as also seen in your screenshot). But you are right - a simple `UPDATE` should do the trick. Thanks again for this great solution. I will wait some more days if other answers appear, before accepting.

Comment: What about `ST_ForceRHR`? This answer actually seems alright.

Comment: @JakubKania I tried to come up with a `ST_ForceRHR` solution, but was not successful. Would be thankful for hints... I tried `ST_Dump(ST_Boundary(ST_ForceRHR(the_geom)))`

Comment: Great answer ! I have been studying this code for the past 2 hours, and I still don't understand the need for the group by. What am I missing ?