# How to check which geometry is rectangle?

Tags: postgis, polygon, geometry

I am doing a assignment in which I created spatial tables for 3 warehouse location. These 3 warehouses has polygon geometry. I want add query to show which gemetry is not rectangle.
Below is table I created:
[image: this table shows the name of the warehouse and its POLYGON coordinates]

Comment: If you check [basic definition of "a rectangle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle) you may see *"A rectangle is a quadrilateral with four right angles."* So, probably you will need to [1] calculate [interior angles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33715529/calculate-the-angle-of-exterior-rings-postgis-polygons-multipolygons) if they all are  90° and [2] check if [opposite sides are equal in their length](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147625/postgis-polygon-edge-analysis-orientation-edge-length).

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to tell if four lines (or four points) form a rectangle, and you just need to know how to implement that in SQL? eg check side lengths and diagonal lengths? https://www.onlinemath4all.com/how-to-check-if-given-four-points-form-a-rectangle.html

Comment: What is a rectangle when dealing with unprojected data? Let's not forget that a degree of longitude does not have the same ground length at various latitudes, and that angles are a bit more complex over a sphere than over a flat surface..

Comment: Because the geodetic distances are very small, it's probably reasonable to compute as if the geometries were planar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using projected data, you can check if the [minimum oriented bounding box](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_OrientedEnvelope.html) of the geometry is the same as the original geometry. Since a bounding box is a rectangle, you can deduce that the input is also a rectangle.

```sql
with src (id, geom) as ( values 
   (1,'polygon((0 0, 0 1, 1 1,1 0, 0 0))'::geometry),
   (2,'polygon((0 0, 0 1, 1 2,1 0, 0 0))'::geometry))
select id, ST_Equals(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom),geom) is_rectangle
from src;

 id | is_rectangle
----+--------------
  1 | t
  2 | f
(2 rows)
```

Comment: This doesn't allow for slight inaccuracies in the input data.  To handle this you could compute the Hausdorff distance between the rings of the input polygon and the oriented envelope and test if it is less than a desired amount (possibly a percentage of the perimeter or area?)

Comment: Or just `SELECT ..., ST_Area(geom) / ST_Area(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom)) > 0.99` - no need to care for vertex count/order, simple and efficient.

Comment: @geozelot yes, that's simpler, but won't detect narrow "gores".

Comment: @dr_jts I mean, neither does comparing diagonals - obviously being unreliable for anything but `ST_NPoints = 5` (but those rectangular shapes do exist...); no chance to detect 2 diagonals (one, yes, e.g. `ST_LongestLine`) and it's vulnerable to anomalies, e.g. with `'POLYGON((0 0, 0.5 0, 1 0, 1.5 0, 0.75 1, 0 0))'`, which, I believe, is a *triangle* with a perfect ratio. Hausdorff is equally vulnerable to outliers, e.g. `'POLYGON((0 0, 0.5 0.4, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))'`. The equality approach here leaves us with no tolerance at all, which is, as we know, not fitting for floating point precision.

Comment: So, for all those cases which cannot hold that very strict set of requirements, i.e. "*has 4 corners / 5 vertices*" - and this one requirement is needed for both approaches, comparing diagonals and making the equality check more likely to succeed - one of the most reliable, general purpose 'rectangularity' checks is comparing *Polygon* area with the minimum oriented envelope. *And* it's equally precise for the 5 vertices case...

Comment: The triangle with multiple vertices on an edge is a clever failure case, for sure.  So yes, comparing areas is required as well.

Comment: For the "indented rectangle" case, I think the Hausdorff distance will catch the outlier?

Comment: @dr_jts it does - sorry, I used the wrong WKT; here `'POLYGON((0 0, 0.5 0.99, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))'` the concavity is extreme, almost touching the other side. The Hausdorff implementation (probably your own?) iterates the minimum vertex to vector distance between geometries, and here it returns `0.01` (with the oriented envelope - so not exactly bad, and I do see why the algorithm needs to do it that way). Fréchet distance doesn't work well with uneven vertex distributions. ...I know I am kinda being a smarta** here. Yet, I learned to think general robustness before anything.

Comment: @geozelot I see the issue with the simple Hausdorff distance now.  What's needed is the densified Hausdorff distance, by providing a densify fraction argument to `ST_HausdorffDistance`.

Answer (score 4):

If rectangles are required to have exactly 4 corners, then only polygons where `ST_NPoints(geom) > 5` need to be considered.

To test quadrilaterals for rectangularity, compare the lengths of their diagonals. In a rectangle the diagonal lengths are (almost) equal.  Since finite numerical precision means the lengths will rarely be exactly equal,
a tolerance factor is needed  To use a dimension-free tolerance the lengths can be normalized by the total length.

Here's a query computing the "rectangularity ratio" from your data and a perfect rectangle:

```
WITH data(id, geom) AS (VALUES
  (1, 'POLYGON((144.78116 -37.824855, 144.780843 -37.826916, 144.782018 -37.827019, 144.78232 -37.82496, 144.78116 -37.824855))')
 ,(3, 'POLYGON((153.193238 -27.682795, 153.19302 -27.68375, 153.193568 -27.683843, 153.193795 -27.682894,153.193238 -27.682795))')
 ,(4, 'POLYGON ((153.1931 -27.6828, 153.1937 -27.6828, 153.19370000000004 -27.6838, 153.1931 -27.6838, 153.1931 -27.6828))')
)
SELECT id,
     (ST_Distance( ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 1), ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 3))
   -  ST_Distance( ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 2), ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 4)))
   / (ST_Distance( ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 1), ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 3))
   +  ST_Distance( ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 2), ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 4))) AS rect_ratio
FROM data;
```

which gives the result:

```
 id |      rect_ratio      
----+-----------------------
  1 | -0.025764420345746754
  3 |  -0.02484385683541937
  4 | 6.269495874867416e-12
```

Comment: This is really helpful. I'm so grateful. I used ST_NPoints(geom) > and it worked

Comment: As pointed out above, just checking the "diagonal" lengths does have a failure case (triangle with multiple vertices on one edge).  So there needs to be an area check or an angle check as well to eliminate this.